# Is it legal in the UK to 3D print a firearm design if it is made impossible to fire?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, firearms, is-x-legal

In the UK firearm regulations are very strict, but I would like to learn about them like in the other countries.
Is it okay to print 3D gun designs if I make sure none of the parts can shoot real bullets by using weak plastic that would explode in the hand if fired with a real bullet?

Answer (score 3):

**Is it legal in the UK to 3D print a firearm design if it is made impossible to fire?**

**Maybe, maybe not**

If the result is merely a toy, trinket etc then there is no offence *per se*.  However it will be unlawful if it meets the definition at [s.57 of the Firearms Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/27/section/57?timeline=false) of a firearm, or used as an "imitation firearm" to commit [any number of offences in the Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/27/part/I/crossheading/prevention-of-crime-and-preservation-of-public-safety?timeline=false):

> (1) "firearm” means-
>
> (a) a lethal barrelled weapon
>
> ...
>
> (c) a relevant component part in relation to a lethal barrelled weapon
>
> ...
>
> 3(1B) In subsection (1)(a), “lethal barrelled weapon” means a barrelled weapon of any description from which a shot, bullet or other missile, with kinetic energy of more than one joule at the muzzle of the weapon, can be discharged.
>
> (4)(b)...“imitation firearm” means any thing which has the appearance of being a firearm ... whether or not it is capable of discharging any shot, bullet or other missile

Comment: It *is* legal to own an immitation firearm in a couple of scenarios which are trivial to achieve for a normal user - if you are a licensed airsoft gamer (find a local airsoft club, attend a few times and register), or if substantial parts of the weapon are bright fluorescent colours (how you can buy an airsoft weapon if you arent a registered airsoft gamer - the seller will spraypaint your weapon for you - mine came with the lower half bright orange).

Comment: Possession of an imitation firearm is not unlawful - it's what one does with it that makes it so. And one doesn't need to go to great lengths to get one either, just pop down to the local greengrocers for a [banana](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/uk-england-dorset-48666853)

Answer (score 2):

In Germany, there are similar prohibitions against building a firearm **or significant parts of a firearm**, and also against gadgets which give the appearance of a firearm.

I expect that it would be possible 3D print something which meets neither definition, but doing so is tricky for an amateur. When a German IT publisher [printed a gun](https://www.heise.de/make/meldung/Auf-dem-Schiessstand-Die-Pistole-aus-dem-3D-Drucker-1972516.html) some years ago, they played it safe and let a licensed gunsmith do it.